# Venn Diagram with restrictions

Tags: probability, inclusion-exclusion

100 people play only football , 30 only play basketball and 20 play both
football and basketball

The question is to find

P(A)

P(B)

P(AUB)

Now after drawing a Venn diagram

P(A)=120/150

P(B)=50/150

P(AUB)=(100/150 + 50/150) -20/150  using the addition formula[image]
= 1

is this the correct solution?

Comment: My doubt is that how can AUB be 1?

Comment: $P(A\cup B)=1$ because there are no people (at least in the part of the question that is given) that do not play either football or basketball. There would have to be a positive number outside both ellipses (but within the rectangle) for $P(A\cup B)$ to be smaller than $1$.

Comment: Your $100/150$ should instead be $120/150$.

Comment: In order to have a probability $P(A),$ you need $A$ to be an *event*. You are given that $120$ people play football, but that group of people do not constitute an event. If we also assume that one person will be chosen at random from among all the people who play either football or baseball, then one event we can describe is the event that the person we chose plays football. If you write out clearly what probability space we are looking at (picking a person at random from a group, or something else) and what *events* you are looking for, the reasons for the results might be clearer.